# MongoDB - select distinct values from a collection where values are separated by comma

Tags: mongodb, distinct

To get the list of distinct values from DB and the collection called 'names' is as easy as doing this:

```
db.name.distinct('names')
```

However, I inherited a MongoDB where `names` contain values separated by a comma.
So doing `db.name.distinct('names')` returns JSON that contains values like this:

```
names
--------
[
"name1,name2",
"name2,name3",
"name4,name1,name3"
]
```

I need to get the list of distinct values from 'names', so it looks like this:

```
names
--------
[
"name1",
"name2",
"name3",
"name"
]
```

Do I need to go about this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$reduce` names array as input, `$split` value with `,` and it will return array, `$setUnion` will join array and get union/unique array from set,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      names: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$names",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [{ $split: ["$$this", ","] }, "$$value"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SrIpya7PJyO)

---

If you want unique names from all records then try,

- `$project` skipped, its same as above query
- `$unwind` deconstruct names array
- `$group` by null and get unique values from name using `$addToSet`

```
  // skipped $project from above query

  { $unwind: "$names" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: { $addToSet: "$names" }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o8DJ8jXSP6I)

Comment: much appreciate your time and experience... thanks, this worked like a charm,

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? It seems that some values are separated by a single comma: ",", but others are separated by comma and space: ", " or " ,". Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: Now I struggle with sorting the output, adding   { $sort: {names: -1}} doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions? A new example is here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vrPKKnUpfHY